# How can I make stacked dot plots using a facet in GGplot2? R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid, dot-plot

I am trying to stack dot plots using a facet in GGplot2.

My first dot plot:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(marathon, aes(x = MarathonTime, y = first_split_percent)) +
  geom_point()
plot1
```

[image]

My second:

```
plot2 <- ggplot(marathon, aes(x=MarathonTime, y=km4week)) +
  geom_point()
plot2
```

[image]

I am trying to stack them on top of each other as they share the same x-axis. I have tried using facet_wrap as so:

```
plot3 <- ggplot(marathon, aes(x = MarathonTime, y = first_split_percent)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(km4week~.)
plot3
```

[image]

I have also played around with the 'rows = vars(km4week), cols = vars(MarathonTime)' functions but have had no luck. Is there a way to achieve what I am describing without a facet? Or am I using the Facet function incorrectly? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stack your two plots using facetting you first have to reshape your data so that your columns become categories of one column or variable which could then be used in `facet_wrap`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

marathon <- data.frame(
  MarathonTime = runif(100, 2, 4),
  first_split_percent = runif(100, 45, 55),
  km4week= runif(100, 20, 140)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

marathon_long <- marathon |> 
  pivot_longer(c(first_split_percent, km4week), names_to = "variable")

ggplot(marathon_long, aes(x = MarathonTime, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "right", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! I also realized that I could use cowplot::plot_grid() to avoid faceting. I am going to use your solution though!

Comment: Yeah. Of course. That would be the second approach. But I would prefer to use the `patchwork` package for this. In general it works better when it comes to glueing plots.